# Disable Button During Postback With Server-Side Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

Been through a few threads and wasn't able to find this situation exactly. My page is ASP.NET 4.5, C#. I use "Server Side" validation for (IMHO) security reasons and have several validation groups on a dynamic form.

I think we are all familiar with the advantages of disabling a button during Postback to prevent double clicking. I've read through quite a few threads with examples using OnClientClick in various ways.

What I'd like my page to do is something like this:

1 -  User clicks Submit (or whatever button)
2 - Server-side custom validation fires on appropriate validation group
3 - if the validation passes, disable the client button(s) and proceed with Postback
4 - if the validation doesn't pass, show the error as usual. Client buttons should still be enabled.

Number 3 seems to be the kicker. Is this even possible with server-side validation? It seems out of order to validate server-side, come back to execute javascript, then back to postback. If it is possible, then I'm muddy on some of the mechanics. Specifically, how to tell the client that the specific validation group passed okay on the server side. Less specifically, the entire thing, lol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ASP.NET, I'm assuming you're also using jQuery (which is the default).

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function (event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  if (!form.data('submit-lock')){// check if we're waiting on the server's response
    form.data('submit-lock', true);// set the lock since we're about to post to the server
    $.ajax(/*your url and data and whatnot here*/)
      .always(function(){
        form.data('submit-lock', false);// the server responded, unlock
      });
  }
});
```

$.ajax() returns a jQuery Deferred promise object.
promise.always(function) registers a function to call when the ajax is resolved (success) or rejected (fail).
More reading on the deferred pattern:
http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/